# NodeJS + MongoDB - find().sort().toArray() does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection "logs" and I need to sort it by most recent first. With `findOne()` I do:

```
.sort($natural: -1)
```

However this is not doing anything now.

```
  db('logs').find({'userId': userId}).sort({ $natural: -1}).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    if (result.length > 0) {
      console.log('Found ' + result.length + ' log entries', result)
      if (callback) callback(result)
    } else {
      console.log('No log entries for ' + userId, userId)
      if (callback) callback(null)
    }
  })
```

This outputs the same as `$natural: 1`. Or if I skip `sort()` all together.

Collection:

```
{_id: "5c044d13f4c6db53a047fe37", dateTime: "2018-12-02 22:22", userId: 5, event: "Failed to update Media Package sale", info: {userId: 5, AmountOfPrePaidItems: 1}}
{_id: "5c044d2bf4c6db53a047fe38", dateTime: "2018-12-02 22:22", userId: 5, event: "Failed to update Media Package sale", info: {userId: 5, AmountOfPrePaidItems: 0}}
{_id: "5c044d56f4c6db53a047fe39", dateTime: "2018-12-02 22:23", userId: 5, event: "Failed to update Media Package sale", info: {userId: 5, AmountOfPrePaidItems: 1}}
```

Using Atlas mongoDB 4.0.4

**Edit 1:**
`.sort( _id: -1)` also gives same output order

Comment: If your sorting was working before, I'd say it's pretty likely that you're accidentally reordering your results outside of the code you're showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what you are trying to do you should simply use:

```
db('logs').find({'userId': userId}).sort({ _id: -1 })
```

if you want to get the most recent first since `_id` contains the date etc.

As far as `$natural` goes:

> The $natural parameter returns items according to their natural order
>   within the database. This ordering is an internal implementation
>   feature, and you should not rely on any particular structure within
>   it.

Using your sample data:

```
db.getCollection('items').find().sort({ _id: -1})
```

You get:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5c044d56f4c6db53a047fe39",
    "dateTime" : "2018-12-02 22:23",
    "userId" : 5,
    "event" : "Failed to update Media Package sale",
    "info" : {
        "userId" : 5,
        "AmountOfPrePaidItems" : 1
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5c044d2bf4c6db53a047fe38",
    "dateTime" : "2018-12-02 22:22",
    "userId" : 5,
    "event" : "Failed to update Media Package sale",
    "info" : {
        "userId" : 5,
        "AmountOfPrePaidItems" : 0
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5c044d13f4c6db53a047fe37",
    "dateTime" : "2018-12-02 22:22",
    "userId" : 5,
    "event" : "Failed to update Media Package sale",
    "info" : {
        "userId" : 5,
        "AmountOfPrePaidItems" : 1
    }
}
```

Notice that top document is:

```
"_id" : "5c044d56f4c6db53a047fe39",
"dateTime" : "2018-12-02 22:23",
```

Doing:

```
db.getCollection('items').find().sort({ _id: 1})
```

Notice that:

```
"_id" : "5c044d13f4c6db53a047fe37",
"dateTime" : "2018-12-02 22:22",
```

Is the top document.

Comment: Hi @akrion! I have tried this too. But I get the output in the same order. I am thinking it has something to do with `toArray()`

Comment: Interesting since I used your data and got different result. See updated answer.

Comment: In the mongo shell I get the same result as you, it works. But my case is in a NodeJS environment, and using `.toArray()`

Comment: @RuneAspvik I get exactly the same results in nodeJS with this: `db.collection('items').find({}).sort({ _id: -1}).toArray((err, res) => ...` where `items` is the exact collection you posted.

Comment: My initial solution worked, so did yours. I had a replica route in my server that caught the request before the one I was working on.